# createElement() + appendChild() -- DOM Methods

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to create an "a" element inside a "div" and in that "a" element I add an "img" image that already exists in the "div" element. I did, however, I doubt because the following code does not work.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(function(div){
      
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("a"))
    div.querySelector("a").appendChild(div.querySelector(".image"))
        // OUPUT
        // <div class="card">
        //     <a>
        //         <img class="image" alt="image-1" id="image-1">
        //     </a>
        // </div>


     // NOT WORK
    div.appendChild(document.createElement("a").appendChild(div.querySelector(".image")))
        // OUTPUT
        // <div class="card">
        //     <img class="image" alt="image-1" id="image-1">
        // </div>
})
```

Comment: Please include the HTML on which this JavaScript runs. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to make it runnable. However, the output from your first set of code appears to produce the output you desire.

Comment: `appendChild` returns the node it appended. So `div.appendChild(document.createElement("a").appendChild(…))` is not appending the `a` to the `div` as you intended, because you _lost_ the reference to that, when you wrote `document.createElement("a").appendChild()` all in one go – which returned the `img` element, so that gets appended to your div now. Stop trying to write everything as one-liners, and use _variables_ to preserve return values of method calls you might still need later on.

Comment: Or, if you insist on writing stuff that’s hard to read - use braces. `(div.appendChild(document.createElement("a")).appendChild(div.querySelector(".image")))`. `(div.appendChild(document.createElement("a"))` returns the newly created & appended `a`, so that now `appendChild` called _on that_ can append the image to the `a` element again.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your help is quite useful, I wrote this code with the purpose of experimenting, so I did it that way specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what @CBroe is suggesting in his first comment (use multiple lines):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(function(div){
      
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.appendChild(div.querySelector(".image"));
  div.appendChild(a);

})
```

I'm concerned that this code is moving the `.image` query into *every* `.card a` tag though.  A single DOM object can have only one parent, and each `appendChild(div.querySelector(".image"))` will change the parent accordingly.