# Using array to store elements doesn't let you change the properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const divArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  document.getElementById("h").innerHTML += `<div id=${i}>hello</div>`;
  divArr.push(document.getElementById(`${i}`));
}
console.log(divArr);

let divArrIndex = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById(`${divArrIndex}`).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  if (divArrIndex > 4) {
    divArrIndex = 0;
  }
  divArrIndex += 1;
}, 1000 / 1);
```

```html
<div id="h">alsdjf;lkajsdf</div>
```

The code above successfully turns all the divs green.

But, when I use

```
divArr[divArrIndex].style.backgroundColor = "green"
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById(`${divArrIndex}`).style.backgroundColor='green';
```

I only get the last div green.
Why?
codepen: https://codepen.io/sai-nallani/pen/KKopOXZ?editors=1111

Comment: prefer to use  [createElement() + appendChild() -- DOM Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68004262/createelement-appendchild-dom-methods)

Answer (score 3):

By reassignment to `innerHTML`, you are destroying and recreating the contents of `#h` in each iteration of the loop. You create `#0`, then discard it and create `#0` and `#1`, then discard those and create `#0`, `#1`, `#2`... So the elements you push into the array don't exist any more in your document (though references to them in `divArr` still keep the garbage collector from destroying them outright).

When you change the colour of `divArr[0]`, you are changing the colour of an element that only exists in memory, but is not in DOM any more. However, `#4` is still the original `#4`, it has not been discarded, since you have performed no further assignments to `innerHTML`.

One solution is to gather all the divs after you have constructed them all. You can use another loop, but the easiest way would be:

```
const divArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#h > div'));
```

(Depending on what you are doing with it next, you may not need `Array.from` since `NodeList` should suffice for many purposes.)

Another solution is to construct elements in their own right, not by changing the parent's `innerHTML`:

```
const hEl = document.querySelector('#h');
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const divEl = document.createElement('div');
  divEl.textContent = 'Hello';
  divEl.id = i;
  hEl.appendChild(divEl);
  divArr.push(divEl);
}
```

This way, every element is created and added to `#h` without affecting any other elements already there.